# Does the US require any level of apolitical-ness from career federal employees?

Tags: united-states, civil-service

We have a question here [Why should public servants be apolitical?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/43509/why-should-public-servants-be-apolitical) which informs us that in Westminster-inspired systems, the career civil service employees can't even tweet their political opinions without being fired for breaching the firewall of public political involvement.

Does anything remotely similar exist in the US for career federal employees? Are they subject to any requirements of apolitical-ness as a condition for their employment?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [Hatch Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hatch_Act_of_1939) of 1937 prohibits US federal employees in the executive branch from participating in certain political activities, such as run for a partisan office or express partisan political views while on official duties. They may express political views while outside the work environment and may even campaign for (or against) candidates.